# How can I split my column 'Venture_name' in to number and string

Tags: pandas

[dataframe head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3p1g.jpg)

I want only the vendor number here.how can i seperate that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) wit seelcting second lists and converting to numbers:

```
df['Venture_name'] = df['Venture_name'].str.split('-').str[1].astype(int)
```

If want both assign back to new columns names:

```
df[['Venture_name', 'Venture_no']] = df['Venture_name'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df['Venture_no'] = df['Venture_no'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use .str.split.

```
df['Venture_name'].str.split('-', expand = True)
```